# Getting NullPointerException after setting value of object by getting data from Volley API

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am setting value of `Team` object in the `parseJSON()` method after getting information form my API.
Even though the variable team has been declared static and initialized and I am using the `this` operator while setting data, data is not set in `team` object and when I do a team.getTeamName() I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Code:

```
public class TeamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private RequestQueue queue;
private String teamName;

private static Team team = new Team();

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.team_activity_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    teamName = intent.getStringExtra("teamName");

    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

   
    parseJSON();

    Log.i("Team", this.team.getTeamName());


}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void parseJSON(){
    String url = "http://192.168.0.174:8080/team/" + teamName;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {

                try {
                        this.team.setId(Long.parseLong(response.getString("id")));
                        this.team.setTeamName(response.getString("teamName"));                            
                        this.team.setTotalMatches(Long.parseLong(response.getString("totalMatches")));
                        this.team.setTotalWins(Long.parseLong(response.getString("totalWins")));

                       
                        }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                      
                }
            }, error -> Log.i("ERROR","Couldn't parse JSON"));

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` error means `team.getTeamName()` is `null` (and body of log can't be `null`). thats obvius as you are calling `Log` just after QUEUEING request (`parseJSON`). Volley will queue this request, send it, get response and then will call your callback with fetched data (or error). this will take few milisecs at least, as this is IO ASYNCHRONOUS operation, in the meanwhile you are trying to `Log` empty data

move your `Log` call INTO callback, just after setting parsed data to your `static Team` object. then it will work and print your name

```
this.team.setTeamName(response.getString("teamName"));
Log.i("Team", this.team.getTeamName()); // moved from onCreate
```

btw. `Team team` probably shouldn't be set as `static` and even initialised. as long as it is `null` you will know that your code didn't fetched data (yet). inside callback create `tempTeam = new Team();`, parse data and set to this local instance. then check if everything is parsed well, if yes then attach local-callback `Team` object to `this.team = tempTeam;` and after that your `Log` will "start working"

Comment: Thank you. This answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`private static Team team = new Team();` I assume the constructor is initialising the null for `teamName`, could you please update it to `empty` in the constructor, so that the `NullPointerException` can be avoided or check the condition whether its empty or not and log it when its not empty.